# JSON properties now lower case on swap from ASP .Net Core 1.0.0-rc2-final to 1.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I've just swapped our project from ASP .Net Core 1.0.0-rc2-final to 1.0.0. Our website and client have stopped working because of the capitalization of JSON properties. For example, this line of JavaScript now fails

```
for (var i = 0; i < collection.Items.length; i++){
```

because the controller now calls the array "items" instead of "Items". I have made no changes beyond installing the updated packages and editing the project.json file. I have not changed the C# model files which still capitalize their properties.

Why have the ASP.Net Core controllers started returning JSON with lower-cased properties? How do I go back to them honoring the case of the property names from the model?

Comment: see https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194

Comment: For those of you looking for the answer for .Net Core 3 you need to scroll down to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

MVC now serializes JSON with camel case names by default

Use this code to avoid camel case names by default

```
  services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

Source:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194

Comment: netcore2:  using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

Comment: I don't want to change _all_ of my JSON serialization, just one particular case that needs to match the behaviour of some third-party software. How does one provide the correct serialization settings in the second parameter of the `Json()` call?

Answer (score 197):

In case you found this from Google and looking for a solution for Core 3.

Core 3 uses `System.Text.Json`, which by default does not preserve the case. As mentioned with this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10156#issuecomment-491444009), setting the `PropertyNamingPolicy` to null will fix the problem.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

and if you don't want to change the global settings, for one action only it's like this:

```
return Json(obj, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = null });
```

Comment: you are my lord and savior

Comment: This worked well for me on Core 3.1. I couldn't get my kendo components to work properly and found the json to be camel case formatted. This resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm also your subject

Comment: This saved my live!

Answer (score 19):

You can change the behavior like this:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

See the announcement here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194

Answer (score 19):

For those who migrated to Core 3.1 and have Core MVC project can use following setup code in Startup.cs:

---

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
            ...
        }
```

Comment: This is the same as a prior answer stackoverflow.com/a/58187836/125981

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you are probably right, as my answer is similar to all the other ones, however, when I was searching proper answer based on my project type, which is MVC utilizing views, I didn't find exact answer matching my project. AddControllersWithViews() adds those missing piece, and I thought it will be useful for anyone in the future. Thank you though for your comment!

Answer (score 7):

This will fix it in dotnet core 3 webapi, so that it doesn't change your property names at all,  and you return to your client exactly what you intended to.

In Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
        services.AddHttpClient();
    }
```

Comment: This is the same as a prior answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58187836/125981

Answer (score 5):

For someone who does not want to set it globally, it is possible to use ContractResolver also to return as Json result:

```
public IActionResult MyMethod()
{
    var obj = new {myValue = 1};
    return Json(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For ASP MVC Core 6 Web API , Add below code into **Program.cs** file will make sure JSON propreties name follow C# model properties name in right casing on swagger UI. No 3rd party package require

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; 


builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

Comment: This solution worked as well for .Net Core 7. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Install

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

For .net 6 you should select this version: 6.0.13

and then go to Program.cs and configure it like this

```
builder.Services
.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

Comment: this answer helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

For some one who is using ASP.net WEB API ( rather than ASP.NET Core).

Add this line in your WebApiConfig.

```
//Comment this jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

Adding this as an answer here because this comes up first in google search for web api as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Core 2.x versions, using this code you can avoid camel case names by default. You need to add following code inside the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs file.

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(o =>
{
    if (o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver != null)
    {
        var castedResolver = o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
        as DefaultContractResolver;

        castedResolver.NamingStrategy = null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently had this issue with .Net6

The solution turned out to be that I needed to install

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.0.x (Note, use 7.x for .Net 7)

Found this out from Mason's post:

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.2 is not compatible with net5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059522/microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-newtonsoftjson-6-0-2-is-not-compatible-with-net5-0)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to solve this using .NET 6 Minimal API:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    options.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
});
```

Solution from [here](https://www.meziantou.net/configuring-json-options-in-asp-net-core.htm).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; 

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```