# Input type="submit" fails to pass its value to the server if the value starts with the capital letter

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have two buttons in my HTML: Save & Save and Exit.  On the server I check the value of the button and act accordingly.  However if the value of the button starts with a capital letter on the server it is Null.  The lower case letter goes through fine.

Below is my code

//HTML:

```
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  name="submissionbutton" value="Save" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submissionbutton" value="Save & Exit" />
```

//SERVER:

```
        var button = Request.Form["submissionbutton"];
        model.Save(id, db);
        if (button == "Save & Exit")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            model = new EditEquipmentViewModel(id, db);
            return View(model);
        }
```

If I change the value in the input from "Save" to "save", all works fine but then it displays lower case "save" on the button itself, which is undesirable.
I don't understand how changing the value from Lower Case to Upper Case in the input type="button" nullifies it on the server.

Comment: Do you have any rule like "routes.LowercaseUrls = true" or  anything on Application_BeginRequest on the Global.asax. Or any action name like [ActionName("save")]?

Comment: I didn't find such a rule anywhere in my code.  Since changing the case in the value from lower to upper, without changing the name of the key makes the key disappear from the form, is this a bug in MVC.  Or may be there is documentation, which I was unable to find that requires Form keys string Value to start with the Capital letter?  This doesn't quite make a lot of sense.  Does anyone know?

Comment: I originally designed this about 4 years ago and it was working then.  It was either MVC 3 or 4.  I've upgraded MVC, Entity Frame Work and Visual Studio several times since but the users discovered this problem just recently.  So I do not know how long this has been the problem

Comment: When it's uppercase, do you get any error or something? If you cannot solve this issue, maybe you can change input to button and button has also value but that is not for text. It might fix your problem. Can you also show us the result when you click the button on network section from developer tools on your browser?

Comment: I use the VS debugger to understand the issue.  At the break point on the server in my controller I check request=>form=>keys

Comment: When the button's value is lower case I see the key "submitbutton" with the proper value and the total number of keys in my case was 30   When the value is in Upper Case the total number of keys becomes 29 and button key is no longer there.  I didn't see any error messages.  It does work if I change to the button but it creates a slight problem for me with Accessibility Program JAWS (some of my users are visually impaired) since it reads a button different from the link. Most importantly I need to understand this strange behavior - is it in design or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet the issue is actually your ampersand. If that's the case, look at using `encodeURIComponent();`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

> "Without encodeURIComponent the ampersand could be interpretted on the
>   server as the start of a new field and jeopardize the integrity of the
>   data."

I think the above will sanitize the value you're sending and fix the problem. You could also try a button element instead of an input element. This way your value will be whatever you want versus the text displayed on the button. The other way to do it is make your own button out of a div element. I'm not sure if those suggestions will really help though, as I don't work with asp.net myself.

```
<button name="name" value="save" type="submit">Save</button>
<button name="name" value="saveexit" type="submit">Save & Exit</button>
```

Comment: When I read the value of just "Save" it behaves the same - I could get "save" but not "Save"

Comment: The <button> solution does work but I would like to understand why the changing of the Case in the <input value changing the behavior

Comment: pretty sure it's not the case but the ampersand causing unexpected results. Does it work if you replace the ampersand with the word AND just for testing? Like "Save AND Exit" just for a test? If it works that is for sure the issue and I'd go back to encodeURIComponent for that.

Comment: I also tried "save & exit" and it works as well while "Save And Exit" gives me null value on the server

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO:
When I make my button value “save” (lower case) I could see it on the server as one of the form keys

 

As soon as I change the value to “Save”, Form key is no longer on the server – it decreases the number of keys by 1

Comment: Man, that's so strange. Good luck!

Comment: Since changing the case in the value from lower to upper, without changing the name of the key makes the key disappear from the form, is this a bug in MVC.  Or may be there is documentation, which I was unable to find that requires Form keys string Value to start with the Capital letter?  This doesn't quite make a lot of sense.  Does anyone know?

Comment: I originally designed this about 4 years ago and it was working then.  It was either MVC 3 or 4.  I've upgraded MVC, Entity Frame Work and Visual Studio several times since but the users discovered this problem just recently.  So I do not know how long this has been the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it has something to do with how Json serializes form values:

Try this link below:
[JSON properties now lower case on swap from ASP .Net Core 1.0.0-rc2-final to 1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202039/json-properties-now-lower-case-on-swap-from-asp-net-core-1-0-0-rc2-final-to-1-0)

Replace this line:

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

With:

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```