# JSON object property name first letter is changing to non capital char

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Angular 8 , asp.net core 2.0 api

```
export class cms {
  ID: Number;
  adminName: string;
  buName: string;
  Category: string;
  contentInfo: string;
  contentTitle : string;
  contentType: string;
  contentURL: string;
}
```

I have a table that when you click on edit button is calls this method where it assigns the object to variable  selectedContent: cms;    cms is the model

```
showForEdit(con : cms)
{
  this.cmsService.selectedContent = Object.assign({}, con);
  console.log("selected content : " + JSON.stringify(this.cmsService.selectedContent));

  console.log("Edit Bu:  " + this.cmsService.selectedContent.buName);
  console.log("Edit Category " + this.cmsService.selectedContent.Category);
 
  this.getCategoryNamesByBuName(this.cmsService.selectedContent.buName);
}
```

when I console log the whole object it shows the "Category" property changed to "category"
why did the first letter become uncaptialized.

the issue is that Category doesn't show up in console log when i do the this.cmsService.selectedContent.Category but if i do  .category  it shows the value in console
but visual studio code says " Property 'category' does not exist on type 'cms'. Did you mean 'Category'?"

I don't understand why first letter of properties are losing captialization.

[angular cms model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqoKU.png)

[api model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUD9J.png)

[console log of JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk5cT.png)

Comment: In shorter terms the JSON properties are being changed to CamelCase when i didn't code it to do so....

Comment: To be sure if its the client or server changing the values, check the network tab in chrome dev tools. You can see the actual response from the server.  That will help us narrow down what the issue might be.  I'm betting its the server, googling .net core lowercase json got me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202039/json-properties-now-lower-case-on-swap-from-asp-net-core-1-0-0-rc2-final-to-1-0

Comment: I will give that a try, it shows in chrome that it went to lower case, I have default httpclient settings in angular so its not from client side it has to be from api. lol to get around it since its still in dev i changed the field in the database to lowercase first letter. I plain on upgrading my api in the future soon from .net core 2.2 to 3.1 which will change mvc to razer. I appreciate the help !